# simple upload form & double extension

Tags: php, file-upload

I made a simple upload form, but when I try to upload something, the name of the file changes (ex : `photo.jpg` >> `photo.jpg.jpg` - double extension).

My code:

```
$place = realpath($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);
$name = $place.$_FILES['file']['name'];
$f1 = strchr($name,'.');
$f2 = strtolower($f1);
$name = $place.$name.$f2;

if ($_POST['up']) {

    if (file_exists($name)) {
        echo '[-] The File  Already Exist ! ';
    } else {
        $upload = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],$name);
    }
    if (isset($upload)) {
        echo '[+] The File "'.$_FILES['file']['name'].'" uploaded succsessfully';           
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean "double extension"? Well, you get the full filename (which includes the extension) with: `$name = $_FILES['file']['name']` and then you add the extension to it: `$name = $place.$name.$f2` (you extracted the extension into `$f2` in the rows above). But for next time, please ask a question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because how you create the `$name` variable.

You first create `$name = $place.$_FILES['file']['name'];` Where `$_FILES['file']['name']` is the full name of the file. With the extension.

After that you say that `$name` is the path (which makes no logic) and you add the full name of the file and the extension again. Just remove the second `$name = $place.$name.$f2;`